# Push Associate array into another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I would like to push an associate array into another array but I an not sure how to go about it. At the minute I have the following:

```
$rate_info = array(
    "hotel_rating" => $hotel->{'hotelRating'},
    "room_rate" => $hotel->{'RoomRateDetailsList'}->{'RoomRateDetails'}->{'RateInfo'}->{'ChargeableRateInfo'}->{'@total'},
    "currency" => $hotel->{'RoomRateDetailsList'}->{'RoomRateDetails'}->{'RateInfo'}->{'ChargeableRateInfo'}->{'@currencyCode'},
    "deep_link" => $hotel->{'deepLink'}
);

array_push($hotel_array[$hotel->{'name'}]["offers"],  "expedia" => $rate_info );
```

"Offers" is an array , all I want to do is add an key value with an array within in. Any ideas? All I seem to be getting at the minute is parse errors.

UPDATE

This is the output of the array so far

```
["offers"]=>
array(2) {
  ["LateRooms"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["hotel_rating"]=>
    int(4)
    ["room_rate"]=>
    string(6) "225.06"
    ["currency"]=>
    string(3) "USD"
  }
  [0]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
```

As you can see instad of [0] I would like ["site"]=>array()

Thanks

Oliver

Comment: What bit is generating parse errors? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Incidentally, you can replace `$hotel->{'RoomRateDetailsList'}->{'RoomRateDetails'}` (etc) with `$hotel->RoomRateDetailsList->RoomRateDetails` (etc). The last one on the end (`@total`) looks very dodgy too - is the `@` necessary?

Comment: It is sending back the parse error for the line: array_push($hotel_array[$hotel->{'name'}]["offers"],  "expedia" => $rate_info );

Comment: Thanks, the @ sign is the name of the field sent back by the api

Comment: Comment on your array structure: should 'LateRooms' only have one hotel (i.e a hotel_rating, room_rate, currency)? Or should that be an array of these records, so that you can have several against LateRooms?

Comment: Your answer below solved the problem, thanks. I just needed to change the way in which I was adding the new values to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this for the array assignment:

```
$hotel_array[$hotel->name]['offers']['expedia'] = $rate_info;
```

Ensure your warnings are enabled, so you know arrays (and subarrays) have been set up before you use them.

Answer (score 1):

Did you first do this?

```
$hotel_array[$hotel->{'name'}] = array();
```

And then you can do:

```
array_push($hotel_array[$hotel->{'name'}]["offers"],  "expedia" => $rate_info );
```

Comment: Hi, see above I have updated the question. The "name" is a key value the contains an array. Within the array there is another array called "offers".